# Upgraded to 14.04, now I can't even log in

Tags: 14.04

My Ubuntu has been telling me almost 3 weeks now to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04, so yesterday I finally did it. But now I can't even log in. No password asking, no anything.. Can't get to the terminal, can`t do anything.

When I try to login I get only the usual purple background that says Ubuntu. Then it goes black. A white message box gives me a message that I have to manage by myself and what do I want to do (see the screenshot below). Well, I want it to work! I don't even know how to get to the terminal or what to write in it.

[image]

Comment: What does the screen look like when you  can't login?... your normal login screen, a black screen, a black screen with incomprehensible error messages?

Comment: Only usual pupple backround, that saes ubuntu. then it goes black.
White cube tells me that I have to manage by my self and what do i want to do.

Well, I want it to work! I dont even know how to get to terminal or what to write to it..

Sorry about my bad english and my bad computer skills..
And no, I don`t have any friends who could help me

Comment: Now I'm looking for your white cube so I can see exactly what it says. Does it look like the screenshot in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)? If it does, I'll add the screenshot to your question.

Comment: Yes! thats the one!

Comment: I had a problem that I got the same screenshot as in your question. I was stuck at that screen and I couldn't login. What I did was pushed down the power button for 5 seconds to shutdown the computer and then waited for 2-3 minutes for the computer to cool off and started it again. This time it booted to my normal login screen and I could login and fix the problem. In my case the problem had something to do with my graphics processor which explains why I got the error message about _running in low-graphics mode_.

Comment: I really, really hope that this is the case.
Thank you so much.

I will never ever update anything again :(

Comment: I have two different possible ideas about how to solve your problem. If you can login, you need to run two commands from the terminal. Use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T to open the terminal and run: `lspci -nn | grep VGA` and post the results in a comment. Based on the results I will tell you the second command to run. The results of running the second command will hopefully point to a solution to your login problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in Ubuntu 14.04 which prevents login if the user's home directory was encrypted and the user changed the password during upgradation. Is that the case with you?

You can review the option as in [Comment #8](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1308530) on the Launchpad. You can try signing into the terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 (to F6).

Comment: No, no I did not change anything (with my skills, I dont even know how to do that)

Answer (score 0):

ITs because your lightdm is crashed. Do the following things

Press ALT+CTRL+F1

You will get tt1

Login as **username = root**

Password what you set for you system

Now enter the following lines

**vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf.dpkg-bak**  //an editor opens b4 u

Delete what is there and add the following lines

[SeatDefaults]

greeter-session=unity-greeter

user-session=ubuntu

greeter-show-manual-login=true

Also edit the following file

**vim /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf**

[SeatDefaults]

greeter-session=unity-greeter

user-session=ubuntu

greeter-show-manual-login=true

**Now Restart the system using the following command**

init 6   //Reboot system